# React js Spring boot and findbyId

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, api, findby

Hello everyone i need to update my object but when i try to get this object i get some error at front end 
with react js 
the code is :

```
class Updateregion extends    Component
{  path= window.location.pathname; 

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state={
            listeupdate : []
          }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/regions/regionid/"+this.path.substring(14))
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then((data) =>{
          this.setState({listeupdate : data})

        })



      }
    render(){
      const {listeupdate} = this.props;



           return(

        <div> 

            <Menu/>

            {this.state.listeupdate.map((listeupdate)=>(



             {listeupdate.name}

            ))
          }
```

the code backend :

```
@GetMapping("/regionid/{id}")
    public Optional<Region> getRegionId(@PathVariable Long id){

        return rp.findById(id);

    }
```

my erorr is : 
TypeError: this.state.listeupdate.map is not a function
please what i should to do to get my data

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your API return a single object as it uses a `findById`.
You can log what is the data received in the response of axios to confirm this.

If so you can do the following if you want to keep an array:

```
this.setState({listeupdate : [data]})
```

On a side note, be careful that listeupdate name is used both as the value coming from the props and the value used in the map iteration

Comment: @ELMANDPURAMINE What do you mean? You have another error?